# How do i replace words in a .RTF file without destroying/corrupting the whole layout

Tags: c#, rtf

So I am making an application that will take User info and paste it in a .RTF file. But when i try to paste the info into that file it will change the words but it will change the whole layout. The imagine, font, colours and links are all removed/changed and i don't know why.

> As you can see the first picture is what i use for testing and the second picture is the outcome i get by only changing "BaseName".

Original

[image: This is the original]

Outcome

[image: This is the outcome]

```
// ENC is a Encoding code i tried to use but no results
// TempPathRTF is the path to the rtf file and I've tested it and it works
// tempUserData.Name is the User's name

var ENC = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1");
            string tempPathRTF = $"D:\\Downloads\\TempImageTesting\\WT-{tempUserData.Name.Replace(" ", "")}.rtf";
            string RTFFile = File.ReadAllText(tempPathRTF);
            RTFFile = RTFFile.Replace("BaseName", tempUserData.Name);
            File.WriteAllText(tempPathRTF, RTFFile, ENC);
```

If anyone knows why or how to write/change text in a .RTF file please let me know.

Comment: Can you link the `Original` rtf file?

Comment: @Magnus i don't know how to put a link of the file in here. But why would you need the file if you don't mind me asking.

Comment: Is that the right text encoding? Maybe it should be Windows-1252.

Comment: I cant test your code without the file.

Comment: @MatthewWatson When i use "Windows-1252" it gives me an error saying: "System.ArgumentException: ''Windows-1252' is not a supported encoding name.".

Comment: @Magnus I would not know how to send a file on here. Is there a website where I can easily give a file a Hyperlink or something in that direction?

Comment: If you're using .Net 5 or later you have to call `Encoding.RegisterProvider(CodePagesEncodingProvider.Instance);` before using Windows-1252.